# Hole punching over http

Tags: http, hole-punching

How can I do the hole punching over http,like I have a server in godaddy
Its port access for tcp listeners is closed,so can I get the client's port
number from its request to an aspx page?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java and have access to the http request on the server side, you can get the remote address and port with the [getRemoteAddr()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29) and `getRemotePort()` methods in the servlet handling the request.